# How come my views are not returned when exported from a file in my routes directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

I'm just experimenting with basic routing in ExpressJS and so far I have two routes:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.render('index');
});

app.get('/pics', function(req,res) {
  res.render('pics');
});
```

When defined like this, in my app.js, everything works fine, but when exported as below, from individual files in my `routes` subdirectory, I get the error message that a callback function was expected, but an Object undefined was returned.

**index.js:**

```
exports.index = function(req,res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

**pics.js**

```
exports.pics = function(req, res) {
  res.render('pics');
};
```

**app.js**

```
var routes = require('./routes');

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/pics', routes.pics);
```

What am I doing wrong in the latter example to break everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index route is working but your pics route isn't because you are trying to import it from index.js.

The route directory has index.js which means that if you do `require('./route')` you are actually doing `require('./route/index')`. This happens because index.js has a special meaning in Node.js.

So to get pics working you need to do:

```
app.get('/pics', require('./routes/pics').pics);
```

This can be really confusing and is a question that gets asked a lot on the IRC channel.

Comment: Thanks. This solved it. But would this means that - in case I have very few views in a given app - I could export them all from index.js?

Answer (score 1):

`require('./routes')` only loads `./routes/index.js`, not `./routes/pics.js`. So `routes.pics` will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

**require()** will try to load index.js.

Here is a small coffeescript snippet that you can paste (convert it to js) in index.js. It will autoload all your files(routes) in the current directory:

**index.coffee**

```
module.exports = (app) =>
  require("fs").readdirSync(__dirname).forEach (file) ->
    i = file.lastIndexOf('.')
    ext = if (i < 0) then '' else file.substr(i)
    if (ext == ".js" or ext == ".coffee") and file != "index"+ext
      require("./" + file)(app)
```

**app.js**

```
require("./routes")(app)
```

**someRoutes.js**

```
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```